# Node Js and SQL Server Connection issue due to firewall

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

I am getting this error in return from server ,here am having strong doubt about firewall blocking my connection but if so how to allow such connection with firewall Rule.

```
{
"message": {
    "code": "ETIMEOUT",
    "originalError": {
        // IP used here is just for an example
        "message": "Failed to connect to 35.200.150.88:1433 in 15000ms",
        "code": "ETIMEOUT"
    },
    "name": "ConnectionError"
}
```

}

Comment: Are you using [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/) as the database service? Where is the Node js server? [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/)? Please edit your post with more contextual information.

Comment: Thank you for your response I have solved my problem , Firewall was blocking SQL  server connection and I was unable to locate the IP of virtual machine. I did found that and I made firewall ingress rule and it worked.

Comment: Cool! I suggest adding and accepting your response so that the community would benefit from your experience. Cheers!

Comment: @Tudormi how to do that?

Comment: you can answer your own question. and accept it as an answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: [just](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)


[google it](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/)